# Subviews out of bounds of NSScrollView respond to mouse event

Tags: events, subview, bounds, nsscrollview

My problem is that the subviews of my scrollView respond to mouse event even if they are not visible (out of the bounds of the visible part of the scrollView).

I've got this architecture :

```
CustomView *view01 = [[CustomView alloc] init];
CustomView *view02 = [[CustomView alloc] init];

NSView *contentView = [[NSView alloc] init];
[contentView addSubview:view01];
[contentView addSubview:view02];

NSSCrollView *scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] init];
scrollView setDocumentView:contentView];
```

With the CustomView implementation :

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@interface CustomView ()
{
    NSTrackingArea *trackingArea;
}
@end

@implementation CustomView

-(id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)contentRect
{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:(NSRect)contentRect])
    {
        [self setFrame:contentRect];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)mouseDown: (NSEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"mouseDown:");

    [NSApp preventWindowOrdering];
}

- (BOOL)shouldDelayWindowOrderingForEvent:(NSEvent *)evt
{
    return YES;
}


-(BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    if(trackingArea != nil)
    {
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    }

    int opts = (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways);
    trackingArea = [ [NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                             options:opts
                                               owner:self
                                            userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}


- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"mouseEntered:");
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"mouseExited:");
}


- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
{
    return NSPointInRect(aPoint, self.frame) ? self : nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

I needed to add the option NSTrackingInVisibleRect in the method :

```
-(void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    if(trackingArea != nil)
    {
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    }

    int opts = (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways| NSTrackingInVisibleRect);

    trackingArea = [ [NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                         options:opts
                                           owner:self
                                        userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}
```

Then, when a part of the CustomView are outside the scrollView, it doesn't respond to mouseEntered and mouseExited.